# uploadedFile not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox

I have an app where I upload a simple .csv file to Dropbox. The files upload perfectly when I send them, but the restClient uploadedFile method is not called. I would like this to use this to display to the user that the file has been uploaded successfully. I seem to remeber it was called the first few times I ran the code, but then it stopped and I can't see why.

Here are some snippets:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 0)       //Cancel
{
}
else if (buttonIndex == 1)      //Send
{
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *CCD = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CCD.csv"];


    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:CCD])
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *machineName = [defaults objectForKey:@"machineName"];
        NSString *fileTitle = [defaults stringForKey:@"setTitle"];
        NSMutableString *filePath = [NSMutableString string];
        [filePath appendString:docPath];
        [filePath appendString:@"/CCD.csv"];
        NSString *destDir = @"/";
        [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sending to %@...", machineName]];
        [[self restClient] uploadFile:fileTitle toPath:destDir
                        withParentRev:nil fromPath:filePath];

    }

} 
}
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient uploadedFile:(NSString*)filePath {
    NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully");
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
};
```

As I said, it uploads the file perfectly, I just don't get the call to the uploadedFile method.

Comment: Whe the code "[[self restClient] uploadFile:fileTitle toPath:destDir
                        withParentRev:nil fromPath:filePath];" gets executed, have you checked the value of "[self restClient]". Is it nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way..

```
@interface ResultClass_vice : UIViewController<DBRestClientDelegate>
{
DBRestClient *restClient;
}

#pragma mark - DropBox

- (void)didPressLink {
   // [[DBSession sharedSession]unlinkAll];

    if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
        // Session must be linked before creating any DBRestClient objects.

        //   nstr
        UIAlertView *al=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"You must have to Login"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [al show];
        [al release];

    }
}

- (DBRestClient *)restClient {
    if (!restClient) {
        restClient =
        [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        restClient.delegate = self;
    }
    return restClient;
}


- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
              from:(NSString*)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

    //NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully to path: %@", metadata.path);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your file is successfully uploaded to Dropbox" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]retain];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"File upload failed with error - %@", error);
}
```

**Let me know if you have any problem because I already implemented it.**

Comment: OK, all I had to do was to change the from: string to srcPath. I was under the impression that these names were freely assignable. Apparently not! Thanking you kindly.

Comment: I had:
     -(void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)filePath
              from:(NSString*)fromPath metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {}
Which didn't work. Yours does.

Comment: oh yes! I just paste my latest code & give try to give the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you have changed upload method parameters:

You are using:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient uploadedFile:(NSString*)filePath {
     NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully to path: %@", metadata.path);
}
```

And you should used:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
from:(NSString*)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {
    NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully to path: %@", metadata.path);
}
```

If you change the number of parameters, you are creating a new function, and therefore, Dropbox SDK will not called it.

I hope this would be helpful

Comment: I think it was the names, rather than number of parameters that was the problem. Maybe it was both!